# How would a space station operate if it had a population of roughly 1 billion people?

Tags: science-based, society, space, space-colonization, space-constructs

This space station would have artificial gravity similar to Earth's. It would not be orbiting a planet, but instead be orbiting a much larger celestial body, such as a star. Population growth is solved by expanding the station.

Edit: What I'm asking is, what makes this any different than the International Space Station or a large city on Earth?

Comment: By "operate" what do you mean? Are you asking what these people do as an occupation, how their life support systems work, what the lifestyle is like, etc?

Comment: That's no space station, that's a good sized planet

Comment: @nzaman: And probably wouldn't need artificial gravity.  Just the humans alone would mass somewhere around 10^11 kg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be several ministries dealing with various problem life in deep space rises.
Ministry of Food, Ministry of Energy, Ministry of dunno water?
The station would have to have armed forces to keep the population in check and a fleet to protect the station from attacks. The fleet would need to be supplied and maintained so large docks would be built.

It just depends on your imagination from here on.

Comment: A little tip about markdown: to get a soft linebreak you have to place two spaces at the end of the line before hitting Enter. There is also a little box at the top of where you type your post. In that box you can find a lot of help. Or you could "propose an edit" by clicking on the "edit" button of other people's post - which allows you to have a look at how they are doing something (no need to propose an edit if you don't want to - you can simply click cancel; I just find that useful when encountering complicated stuff like MathJax).

Answer (score 2):

It would operate like super-megapolis, a gigantic hypertrophied city, with a population of one billion people. There would be additional technical services to cope with the rigours of deep space & orbiting a star. Expansion problems have already been solved (the OP says so).

Answer (score 1):

Space stations actually become easier the bigger they are.

Micro meteorits are less of a problem if you have tons of metal (or water) around you anyways.

Recycling stuff and producing food/air becomes less error prone if you can do it in REALLY large scale and redundantly so.

Artificial gravity through rotation becomes less irritating (different gravity for your feet then for your head) the bigger your station is.

If you can have some thousand of your inhabitants go out and fetch resources, then even extending your space station becomes easier.

What's probably really problematic though, is keeping your people civilized and preventing fires.

And then there's the "tiny" point of how to get something on that scale actually started - it's not like you could move a billion people into space right now (or even over the next some hundred years).